# Glassfish: The expected DDL file is not available

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish, ejb

I'm currently trying to deploy some beans to my glassfish and I've been getting the following exception for 2 hours:

```
[java] Cannot create tables for application dst2_1. The expected DDL file dst2_1_dst_createDDL.jdbc is not available.
```

And I have absolutely no idea where this exception comes from and especially not how I can get rid of it - I don't even know where I could look for problems.

I already tried to start/restart/deploy/undeploy/clean/delete some beans/... but it is always the same freaking error.

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem - it is really annoying.

Thank you :)

Comment: It  seems jdbc driver issue. Did you check jdbc.jar you have is compatible with Glassfish?

Comment: The drivers should be fine since it worked fine until some hours ago. To be honest - i dont even have a jdbc.jar in the classpath or on my computer

Comment: I just had the same problem. Restarting Glassfish resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem. But it occured when I switched from JDK 6 to JDK 7. Switching back to JDK6 worked for me.

Comment: I also had this problem. I tried with MySql,PostgreSQL.(Using eclipselink). But both shows the error. There was also a warning message `Warning: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 16`  
Changing back to JDK6 solved the problem.